# How do I perform a join with a JSONB array structure in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling with the syntax for a join when I've got an array in stored in JSONB. I've searched for examples and I can't find the magic sauce that makes this work in PostgreSQL 9.6

I've got the following structure stored in a JSONB column in a table called `disruption_history`. The element is called `data`:

```
"message": {
        "id": 352,
        "preRecordedMessageList": {
            "preRecordedMessageCodes": [804, 2110, 1864, 1599]
        }
}
```

I then have another standard table called `message_library`

```
component_code       | integer                | not null
message_text         | character varying(255) | not null
```

I'm trying to produce the text for each set of message codes. So something like

```
SELECT
    ml.message_text 
FROM
    message_library ml, disruption_history dh
WHERE 
    jsonb_array_elements_text(dh.data->'message'->'preRecordedMessageList'
->'preRecordedMessageCodes')) = ml.component_code
```

I get

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer

even if I try to cast the numbers to integer I get argument of `WHERE` must not return a set.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but you have an extra closing parenthesis on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

```
select message_library.message_text 
from disruption_history
join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(data->'message'->'preRecordedMessageList'->'preRecordedMessageCodes') v
on true
join message_library
on v.value::int = message_library.component_code
```

Comment: Hey @Oto, do you think there would be merit in highlighting why your solution works.  I am sure it does, but there is always a teaching moment available.

Comment: Thanks, this works too but suffers the same ordering issue as I've described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT
    CAST(dh.data->'message'->>'id' AS INTEGER) AS message_id, 
    ml.message_text 
FROM
    disruption_history dh
    JOIN message_library ml 
        ON ml.component_code IN 
            (SELECT 
                CAST(jsonb_array_elements_text(
                   dh.data->'message'->'preRecordedMessageList'->'preRecordedMessageCodes'
                                              ) 
                AS INTEGER)
            ) ;
```

Note that I have used an *explicit join* (avoid the implicit ones!).

The trick here is to convert your *preRecordedMessageCodes* into a set of *texts*, by using the [`jsonb_array_elements_text` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE), that are further `CAST` to integer, and *then* compared to the `ml.component_code` (by using an `IN` condition):

You can check the whole setup at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=dd608207dca7bd5494f76c6133047308)*

Note also that this structure produces an *awful* execution plan, that requires whole sequential scans of both tables. I have not been able to find any kind of index that helps the queries.

Note that this won't work if you have arrays with `NULL`s in them, which I assume wouldn't make sense.

---

**Keeping order**:

If you want to keep the elements of the array in order, you need to use a `WITH ORDINALITY` predicate to obtain not only the array element, but also its relative position, and use it to `ORDER BY`

```
-- Keeping order
SELECT
    CAST(dh.data->'message'->>'id' AS INTEGER) AS message_id, 
    ml.message_text 
FROM
    disruption_history dh
    JOIN LATERAL
        jsonb_array_elements_text(dh.data->'message'->'preRecordedMessageList'->'preRecordedMessageCodes')
        WITH ORDINALITY AS x(mc, ord) /* We will want to use 'ord' to order by */
        ON true
    JOIN message_library ml ON ml.component_code = cast(mc AS INTEGER)
ORDER BY
    message_id, ord ;
```

Watch this at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fbea0453edc7fed734c3afbe70316369)*

---

**Alternative**:

If the structure of your json `data` is always the same, I would strongly recommend that you *normalize* your design (at least partially):

```
CREATE TABLE disruption_history_no_json
(
    disruption_history_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    message_id INTEGER,
    pre_recorded_message_codes INTEGER[]
) ;

CREATE INDEX idx_disruption_history_no_json_pre_recorded_message_codes
    ON disruption_history_no_json USING GIN (pre_recorded_message_codes) ;
```

Would allow for a much simpler and efficient and simpler query:

```
SELECT
    message_id, 
    ml.message_text 
FROM
    disruption_history_no_json dh
    JOIN message_library ml 
        ON ml.component_code = ANY(pre_recorded_message_codes) ;
```

Check everything together at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6cde18290c14c18af22c781ef2c2248c)*

`JSON(B)` allows you not to normalize, and not to have to think much about your table structures, but you pay a steep price in performance and maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. This works however the codes in the JSON array are processed in a seemingly random order. I need them to be converted into text in the order in that array as they form a readable sentence. In my case I'm getting 'Marble Arch .  is closed station" rather than 'Marble Arch station is closed.'

This is the same for the answer from @Oto  as well which works as well. Not sure which is the most efficient way of doing this of course.

Comment: Relational theory doesn't have the concept of *order*, so most of what you do in SQL doesn't have it either, unless you explicitly ask for a given order. You didn't specify *this* as a requirement. Never assume an order in SQL. See the updated versions that *keeps the order*.

Comment: That's nailed it, thanks a lot. I understand the lack of order in SQL. I just forgot to add it as a requirement :-)

As you say it would be better to normalise but this is part of a complex changing structure, kind of the thing that the JSONB structure is used for.